# Taskbar shortcuts fail, Anaconda with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

I recently reset my desktop, but when I re-installed [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) I have problems I've never seen before. Before the reset I was able to have shortcuts for both the [Navigator](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-navigator) and [Spyder](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder) on my taskbar. After the reset, neither works. Also, when I launch Navigator, I have 3-5 other windows pop up before the navigator even starts. Was there a major change? Should I install an older version?

Comment: I am using the newest anaconda available on the anaconda website as of 1/23/2019. The installation was Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe and I don't believe any updates have occurred. I do have 2 short videos of the behavior, but I don't know if I can upload them.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification question. I was referring to the one from anaconda.com.

Comment: I installed a new version, it still fails. Using Windows 10, but I can open it from the startup menu, thus I can live with it, I guess. Ping me, if there is an answer, please.